# Query one to many relationship mongo db

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How do i query an document with one to many relation ship. When i try to query i get the object id as a reference but i want the document.

```
await Schedule.find({});
```

returns

```
"scheculde": [
        {
            "_id": "63a4b45275be846cf3ed135d",
            "date": "2023-01-01T23:00:00.000Z",
            "timeSlots": [
                "63a4b45275be846cf3ed134c",
                "63a4b45275be846cf3ed134d",
                "63a4b45275be846cf3ed134e",]
```

it returns object id. but i want it to return:

```
 {
    _id: new ObjectId("63a4b45275be846cf3ed134c"),
    slot: '11:00',
    isBooked: false,
    isCompleted: false,
    service: 'HAIRCUT',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63a4b45275be846cf3ed134d"),
    slot: '11:30',
    isBooked: false,
    isCompleted: false,
    service: 'HAIRCUT',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63a4b45275be846cf3ed134e"),
    slot: '12:00',
    isBooked: false,
    isCompleted: false,
    service: 'HAIRCUT',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63a4b45275be846cf3ed1353"),
    slot: '14:30',
    isBooked: false,
    isCompleted: false,
    service: 'HAIRCUT',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63a4b45275be846cf3ed1351"),
    slot: '13:30',
    isBooked: false,
    isCompleted: false,
    service: 'HAIRCUT',
    __v: 0
  },
```

instead of just object id

Answer (score 0):

the answer is adding

```
await Schedule.find().populate("timeSlots");
```

returns what is want